# Как выгрузить в файл формата csv bool, чтобы в файле отображалось ИСТИНА или ЛОЖЬ? (c#)

Tags: c#, excel, csv

Я выгружаю файл формата csv следующим образом

```
                var file = new StringBuilder();
                file.AppendLine("Заголовок1;Заголовок2");
                foreach (var code in codes)
                    file.AppendLine($"{data.Code};{data.IsActivated}");
                return Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(file.ToString());
```

Как правильно реализовать выгрузку в csv файл bool значения, чтобы в столбце отображалась ИСТИНА или ЛОЖЬ (выгружать не через string)? Можно ли корректно выгрузить файл через StringBuilder?

Comment: UTF32 на UTF8 поменяйте, а для работы с CSV есть прекрасный NuGet пакет CSVHelper.

Answer (score 5):

```
data.IsActivated ? "ИСТИНА" : "ЛОЖЬ"
```

т.е. заменяем

```
file.AppendLine($"{data.Code};{data.IsActivated}");
```

на

```
file.AppendLine($"{data.Code};{data.IsActivated ? "ИСТИНА" : "ЛОЖЬ"}");
```

---

И конвертация наоборот:

```
var isActivated = (someStrValue == "ИСТИНА")
```